# How to print a ViewBag string that was populated within a try/catch block

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I am parsing a JSON file in my controller and have try/catch functionality.  The catch for the JSON populates the ViewBag and I want to print it in the view if there is an error.  However the ViewBag.Error does not print to the screen.  I broke into the view and the string is there. It just doesn't print.

This is the relevant code from the Controller:

```
catch (JsonReaderException jex)
{
            ViewBag.Error = "JSON Parsing Error: " + jex.Message;
            return View();
 }
```

This is my view:

```
@if ((string)ViewBag.Error != "")
{
   @Html.Label((string)ViewBag.Error)<br>
}
```

Comment: You're misunderstading `@Html.Label`.  Just print it directly.

Comment: @SLaks he might be using it for styling, although I doubt it. The cast of the dynamic type isn't necessary. Still shouldn't stop the text from printing.

Comment: can you use `@Html.Raw` instead of label and try it. Some thing like this 
`@Html.Raw((string)ViewBag.Error)`

Comment: @ISHIDA: That's an XSS hole.  _Don't do that_.

Comment: @SLaks I agree but he is not entering any data, he is just displaying it (it's a label in his question).

Comment: @Html.Raw worked!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the period(.) character in your exception message.Look at the json exception message and you usually will find a dot(.) in it.

HTML label element gets confused if you have a point . in the **first parameter** because it expects a property expression there.

Use `Label(string expression, string labelText)`  instead.
Ex:`@Html.Label("",ViewBag.Error)`

As @sLaks has pointed ..HTML.Raw is not the appropriate element to use for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You should just print the value directly:

```
@ViewBag.Error
```

**Do not call `Html.Raw()`**, since your value is not HTML.

Answer (score 0):

**ViewData and TempData require typecasting and null checking whereas ViewBag doesn't need such checking.**

If you interested for More info kindly refer here:http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/36941654-8bd4-4535-9226-ddf47841892f.aspx

**So in your view you can simply write like below:**

```
   @ViewBag.Error
```

Wherever you want to display the error message.

Hope it was helpful

Thanks

Karthik